# Check if variable is sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this piece of code in my Node.js API and I feel like it could (*should*) be optimized.

```
var apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.route('/user/:username')
.put(function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        username: req.params.username
    }).exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
        res.json({
            success: false,
            message: 'User not found'
        });
    } else {
        // This is the part to optimize
        if (req.body.firstname) {
            user.firstname = req.body.firstname;
        }
        if (req.body.lastname) {
            user.lastname = req.body.lastname;
        }
        if (req.body.email) {
            user.email = req.body.email;
        }
        if (req.body.username) {
            user.username = req.body.username;
        }
        if (req.body.password) {
            // no worries about this, I hash the password before it is saved
            user.password = req.body.password;
        }

        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'User updated'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

I use this to update my user. In the future I could (*will*) have way more parameters than these.

Is there a scalable solution?

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
var form = req.body;
user.firstname = form.firstname ? form.firstname : user.firstname;
user.lastname = form.lastname ? form.lastname : user.lastname;
// ...
```

Problem is that I'm not sure it is more scalable. I feel like it is just another way to write if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
var fields = ["firstname","lastname","user","email","password"];

fields.forEach(function(field) {
  if (req.body[field]
  {
    user[field] = req.body[field]
  }
});
```

It requires EcmaScript 5+. If you don't have it, use one of the other array iterators.

If these are the only properties of `req.body` you could also use:

```
for (field in req.body) {
  if (req.body.hasOwnproperty(field)) {
    user[field] = req.body[field];
  }
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript for more information about these "foreach" type constructs.

Comment: For reference, Node implements most if not all of ES5, including `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Answer (score 5):

I do not believe the current answer solves your optimization need, I believe the correct answer is to use`findOneAndUpdate`.  This will cut down on the steps need to achieve this same goal.  The update function will handle all of the if checks, it will only update fields supplied in the `req.body`.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: req.params.username }, req.body, function (error, User) {
      if (User) {
        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'User updated'
        });
      } else {
        // ALWAYS RETURN res.send please
        return res.send(err);
      }
    });
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate for additional docs.

**WARNING** If res.body has properties that are set as undefined, it will overwrite existing values.  You should validate inputs coming in to ensure this is not the case.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, Duane. I hope you enjoy the site.

Comment: So this answer may be "wrong" in that the question, after re-reading it for the 12th time, is that they want to optimize checking whether a property on an object is set, My solution doesn't not cover this topic, but rather how to optimize the code completely .... sooooo Im going to leave it here because it does provide value.

Comment: @Duane would this potentially remove key's on the updated object if they're set to undefined? Not sure how OP is validating the properties in req.body

Comment: Very good point, updating answer